# Browser that lets you turn off automatic image loading

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Is there any good alternative to Chrome's Incognito?

It would be cool if it also had the option to turn off image loading.

Comment: Any why exactly is Incognito not working for you? Or are you actually just looking to disable loading of images? Ask about your real problem please, rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: I'm using chrome for image loading and I want another browser for private browsing and non image loading. It is a hassle to switching image loading setting for different task.

Comment: And haven't you tried any other browsers yet to see if they work for you?

Comment: I use two other browsers, firefox and internet explore. Firefox is for regular browsing where I need to save data and passwords. And opera is for testing web design. So i'm looking for another for this task. I don't like Safari.

Comment: Well, obviously Firefox does what you needed, you just have to look more closely :)

Comment: Yes but it time consuming to change the settings back and forth. I need another dedicated browser for private browsing and non image loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All major browsers support [private browsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode):

```
Date                Browser             Synonym
April 29, 2005      Safari 2.0          Private Browsing
December 11, 2008   Google Chrome 1.0   Incognito
February 20, 2009   Arora 0.5           Privacy Mode
March 19, 2009      Internet Explorer 8 InPrivate Browsing
June 30, 2009       Mozilla Firefox 3.5 Private Browsing
February 21, 2010   Shiira 2.3          Private Browsing
March 2, 2010       Opera 10.50         Private Tab / Private Window
March 23, 2010      Maxthon 2.5.12.4534 Private Browsing
```

Comment: pour s'amuser read "Incognito: The Secret Lives of the Brain"

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). In *Options » Content » Load images automatically*, you can disable automatic loading of images.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> starts Private Browsing.